# Comparando textView com txt usando arrayList Android

Tags: android, arraylist

Estou montando um projeto bem simplista no qual exibo os processos que estão executando no android e comparo com uma lista em um arquivo txt que tem outros processos. O intuito é verificar se todos os processos que estão aparecendo no textView, estão no txt. Se aparecer algo no textView e este nao estiver no TXT, seja enviado um alerta mostrando o que esta no textView e não esta no txt. Pensei em uma solução usando arraylist

1- no textview, a saida esta assim

```
com.whatsapp
com.snaptube.premium
com.youtube
com.facebook
```

separados por uma quebra de linha

o meu arquivo de texto esta do mesmo jeito, só que com mais processos. Exemplo

```
com.whatsapp
com.snaptube.premium
com.youtube
com.facebook
com.outroApp
```

o intuito é, se no texview aparecer **algum aplicativo que nao esta no txt** o usuario receber um aviso mostrando que aquele aplicativo nao esta no txt. seria como se cada linha do textview fosse comparada com todas as linhas do arquivo texto. Para isso pensei em 2 for's

o que eu tenho agora:

```
ArrayList<String> texto = new ArrayList<String>(); // array para salvar o que esta no arquivo texto
ArrayList<String> textView= new ArrayList<String>(); // array para salvar o que mostra no textview




            while ( (recebe_string = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                texto.add(recebe_string); // adiciono o que tenho no txt em um array

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { // exibindo no textview                                                         
                textView.add(parteFinal); //adiciono os processos que estao no textview em um array
```

agora vem a parte que nao consigo. Fazer a comparação do que tem no textview com o txt

pensei nisso

```
for (int i = 0; i < texto.size() ;i++) { // percorro array do txt
            for (int ii = 0; ii <textView.size() ; ii++) { // percorro array do textview
                if (textView.get(ii).equals(texto.get(i))) // se tudo que tem no textview tem no txt   nada a fazer
                    teste = false;
                else{ // se tem algo no textView que nao tem no txt, avisa
                    teste = true;
                    virus = textView.get(ii); // capturo o que tem no textview e nao tem no txt
                    System.out.println("virus"+ textView.get(ii)); // exibo o que capturei                       
                }
            }
            }
```

estou com dificuldades nessa parte de comparar. esse metodo que eu fiz ele avisa mesmo que o processo exibido no textView esteja no txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sua lógica está errada em vários aspectos:

- Não sai do *loop* interior quando encontra uma correspondência.
- Como o aviso se encontra dentro do *loop* interior, se o aplicativo a procurar não for o primeiro, mesmo que se encontre na texto, o aviso será apresentado.
- Pode haver mais de um aplicativo que não se encontre na texto.

Proponho que o processo seja feito em 2 fases:

- Primeiro obter uma lista dos aplicativos que não estão na textView.
- Segundo apresentar um aviso por cada um deles.

Código

```
//Encontrar os virus
ArrayList<String> virusList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
for (int i = 0; i < textView.size() ;i++) { // percorro o array textView
    boolean NaoExiste = true;
    for (int ii = 0; ii < texto.size(); ii++) { // percorro o array texto
        if (textView.get(i).equals(texto.get(ii))){ // Foi encontrada uma correspondência
            NaoExiste = false;
            break; //termina o loop interior
        }
    }
    if(NaoExiste){
        virusList.add(textView.get(i)); //Adiciona à lista de virus
    }
}

//Apresentar os avisos
for(String virus : virusList){
    System.out.println("virus "+ virus);
}
```

O comentário do Wakim levou-me a encontrar uma forma mais simples de fazer o que pretende, utilizando o método [removeAll()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%3C?%3E%29) do ArrayList:

```
//Faz uma cópia do array textView
ArrayList<String> virusList = new ArrayList<>(textView);

//Remove os itens de textView que existem em texto
virusList.removeAll(texto);

//Agora virusList contém os itens de textView que não existem em texto.

//Apresentar os avisos
for(String virus : virusList){
    System.out.println("virus "+ virus);
}
```

Comment: Só uma sugestão, será que não seria mais simples usar um `Set` pra evitar iterar sempre (só teria um hehe)?

Comment: Sem problemas :D

Comment: @Wakim Tem razão, não me ocorreu usar um Set. Por norma parto do código do AP para construir a minha resposta. Julgo que a sua sugestão seria:  
`HashSet<String> virus = new HashSet<>(texto);`
`virus.removeAll(textView);`

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas. Porem ele esta exibindo o conteudo total do TXT

Comment: Então é porque as strings não estão iguais no dois ArrayList ou tem espaços ou caracteres especiais. O código que postei está correcto(faltava um `{` veja a edição). Tente fazer `trim()` nas strings ao comparar: `textView.get(ii).trim().equals(texto.get(i).trim())`

Comment: se o problema for caracteres especiais, eu poderia usar o contains()?

Comment: Não porque não sabe quem contem o quê. De qualquer forma não seria a melhor solução. A solução passa por obter as strings correctamente.

Comment: ao analisar a saida, vi que ele apresenta tudo o que ta no TXT exceto o que esta no text view. o que eu queria é o contrario

seria por causa dessa linha?

virusList.add(texto.get(i));

Comment: Estive a ler os comentários no seu código e de facto o que você quer é o contrário. Vou editar a resposta.

Comment: me expressei mal nessa etapa.

então seria só trocar o os contadores do for e na parte de adicionar no arraylist virus, pegar o que tem no text view?  tentei assim e não deu certo

Comment: aparentemente esta funcionando agora

muitissimo obrigado